# Replace string starting with a symbol n times

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace a string starting with a specific symbol '@' with the symbol '%', but the condition is that the symbol should be at the start of the string.

For eg.

`@@@hello@hi@@`

should be replaced by

`%%%hello@hi@@`

I have come up with the regex that matches the starting '@' symbols, but I am able to replace it only once, instead of replacing it with the number of times it matched.

The code is

```
var str = "@@@hello@hi@@";
var exp = new RegExp('^@+', 'g');
var mystr = str.replace(exp, '%');
```

But, it outputs

`%hello@hi@@`

But, the intended output is

`%%%hello@hi@@`

My current solution is something like this:

```
var str = "@@@hello@hi@@";
var match = str.match(/^@+/g)[0];

var new_str = str.replace(match, "");

var diff_count = str.length-new_str.length;
var new_sub_str = Array(diff_count+1).join("%")

var mystr = new_sub_str + new_str;
```

This solution does give me the intended output, but I am worried about the performance.

Is there any better way to achieve this ?

Comment: If your string is guaranteed to begin with `@@@`, you could just do `var result = str.replace(/^@+/g, '%%%');` ?

Comment: No, that was just an example. So the number of occurences may change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a callback function:

```js
var mystr = '@@@hello@hi@@'.replace(/^@+/g, function(match) {
  return Array(match.length + 1).join('%');
});
document.write(mystr);
```

The `Array(n).join(s)` construction is simply a shorthand way of repeating the string `s` `n-1` times.

Comment: Or `return '%'.repeat(match.length)` if you have that available.

Comment: @tor `String.prototype.repeat = function(num){return new Array(++num).join(this)};`

Answer (score 2):

An interesting solution without regexp:

```
var mystr = '@@@@@hello@hi@@'.split('').map(function(item) {
    if (item == '@' && !this.stop) {
      return '%';
    } else {
      this.stop = true;
      return item;
    }
  }, {}).join('');

  console.log(mystr);
```

And an alternative:

```
var mystr = Array.prototype.map.call('@@@@@hello@hi@@', function(item) {
    if (item == '@' && !this.stop) {
      return '%';
    } else {
      this.stop = true;
      return item;
    }
  }, {}).join('');

  console.log(mystr);
```

Comment: nice solution..but this.stop is not defined, so you will have to define it to false first.

Comment: @adirohan Initially the "stop" is `undefined`, so it works a "falsy".

Comment: This will put a `stop` property on the window, probably not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without a callback function as replacement with this pattern:

```
if (mystr.charAt(0)=='@')
    mystr = mystr.replace(/@((?=@)|.*)/g, '%%$1');
```

Obviously, if you already know that the first character is always a @, remove the if condition.

If your string has newlines replace the dot with `[^]` or `[\s\S]`.